# Wrong value returned when trying to get URL params in AngularJs

Tags: angular

I am trying to get URL params from link that looks like this: `localhost:8000\testSession\1&otp="91PVSR"`
Where URL format is this: `localhost:8000\testSession\id&otp="otpvalue"`

I am using stateProvider in my Controller like this:

```
class UserTestSessionController {
    constructor($http, $state, UserTestSessionService, $stateParams) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        this.userTestSessionService = UserTestSessionService;
    }

    startSession() {
        let self = this;
        let sessionId = this.$stateParams.id;
        let otp = this.$stateParams.otp;

        this.userTestSessionService.startSession(sessionId, otp).then(function(data) {
            if(data.isError) {
                self.$state.go("sessionExpired");
            }
            else {
                self.$state.go("testingSession");
            }
        });
    }
}

export default UserTestSessionController;
```

And this is how URL is defined with state:

```
export default angular.module("examino.userTestSession", ["ui.router"])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("testingSession", {
                url: "/testSession/:id?otp",
                controller: "UserTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session.html",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            })
})
```

The problem happens when I try to get ID and OTP values:

`Id=1&otp="someValue"` and `otp` is `undefined`.

[image]

What is the right way to read this values in controller?

Comment: Can you try without the `?otp` part in the state's url specification?

Comment: @SylvainB I just did, values are same? otp value is undefined...

Comment: @nemo_87 Did you've tried to be more precise in specifying your URL template? like this :  url: "/testSession/{id:[0-9]+}?otp"

Comment: @Nedev Yes, I did... For example if I put something like you suggested it won't recognize that URL at all... I mean it doesn't get it that that state belongs to that URL.

Comment: @nemo_87 maybe your problem is caused by opt param quotes, in your example i see localhost:8000\testSession\1&otp="91PVSR" but the correct way is localhost:8000\testSession\1&otp=91PVSR

Comment: I agree with @Nedev, you problem may come from the fact that you've double-quoted your parameter's value. If you want to use double-quotes (") in URLs, you must encode them as %22.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your route declaration. Try this (change in url) :

```
$stateProvider
        .state("testingSession", {
            url: "/testSession?:id:otp",
            controller: "UserTestSessionController",
            templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session.html",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        })
```

And access with $stateParams.id and $stateParams.otp